# #if canImport with SPM

Tags: swift, swift-package-manager

FeatureA package, contains optional Debug code

```
/* FeatureA */
public class Assembly {}

#if canImport(DebugTools)
    import DebugTools

    extension Assembly {
        public var featureToogles: [DebugTools.FeatureToogle] {
            // Some implementation
            []
        }
    }
#endif
```

Framework DebugTools not added in dependencies FeatureA package

```
let package = Package(
    name: "FeatureA",
    platforms: [.iOS(.v12)],
    products: [
        .library(name: "FeatureA", targets: ["FeatureA"]),
    ],
    dependencies: [],
    targets: [
        .target(name: "FeatureA")
    ]
)
```

In App target need if linked DebugTools - use optional property from FeatureA

```
/* App target */
import FeatureA

#if canImport(DebugTools)
    import DebugTools

    let featureToogles: [DebugTools.FeatureToogle] = FeatureA.Assembly().featureToogles
#endif
```

This code success compile without linked DebugTools. But with linked DebugTools, compiler return error: **Value of type 'Assembly' has no member 'featureToogles'**